# What can I do with a disintegration bay?

Tags: sword-of-the-stars-the-pit

These can be interacted with, and sometimes booby-trapped, but:

> they can also spontaneously disintegrate you, ending the game.

Since booby-trapping in general seems to have precious little use, is there any reason to touch these at all? Am I missing something or is there something else to do with these that I haven't discovered yet?

Comment: Aren't they Interrogation bays? :p

Comment: No, there are interrogation pods disguised as med bays, but that's a different thing entirely. Disintegration bays look like a red disc with 3 arms.

Comment: Only thing i could do with them was to booby-trap them. And i have no idea what's the use of booby-trapping anything at all.

Comment: Enemies sometimes use bays to heal themselves (e.g. the Manufacturing Bay heals robots nearby), so I figure if you booby-trap something and then lure an enemy to it, it'd backfire when they use it, although I've never actually managed to do that yet.

Comment: @Ingmar Hmm, the only things I came across that were plantable by explosives are the interrogation pods. What i did came across i think it was with something red aswell are things that gave you a random statboost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If successfully booby trapped, you can lead enemies past it and they will be disintegrated. It's not really worth doing that if you ask me though, as failing to booby-trap can/will disintegrate you (basically instantly kills you). And i think that if enemies get disintegrated by it you wont get any exp from them, which again doesn't make it worth a risk.

Source: [Disintegration Bay](http://steamcommunity.com/app/233700/discussions/0/828933455739710999/)